# Can't access redux store after adding react routing. MapStateToProps is not being invoked

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm learning redux.
Wrote some simple components for fetching data from API.
Everything worked fine until I added routing.

I'm wrapping my Router with Provider. I have route '/cars' and component VisibleCarList which accesses store using connect. When accessing '/cars' via Link or direct URL(tried both, same result) mapStateToProps is not invoked at all, can't see any redux props.

However if I go to for example '/example' with routed App component which has VisibleCarList in it everything works fine.

Spent a few hours already and I still don't understand why it can't connect to the store. Any ideas?

**index.js**

```
const store = createStore( reducer, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddlewares)))

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
       <Router>
          <Route path="/example" component={App}/>
          <Route path="/cars"  component={VisibleCarList}/>        
       </Router>       
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**VisibleCarList**

```
export class VisibleCarList extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCarsPage(0);
    }
    render() {
        ...
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        cars: state.cars,
        pagination: state.pagination,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getCarsPage: fetchCarPage,
    setPage: setCurrentPage,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(VisibleCarList)
```

**App.js**

```
function App(props) {
  return (
        <Box bgcolor="primary.light">
          <NavBar />
           <VisibleCarList></VisibleCarList>           //WORKS FINE
        </Box>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: How are you importing `VisibleCarList` in `App` and in `index`? Your code looks fine except you have two different `export` statements in `VisibleCarList`: a named export for the component and a default export for the redux-connected one.

Comment: My guess is you imported the wrong one (`import {VisibleCarList} from '...') in the index file.

Comment: Oh god... That solved the issue. Didn't notice that named import. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the `import` statement may be wrong.

You have to use `import VisibleCarList from '...';` rather than `import { VisibleCarList } from '...';`.